# Can some tags only be used if another tag is present

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Do there exist some tags that cannot be used unless one or more related tags are also used?

For example say I have programming language "x", which has its own tag.  But it has a feature that is specific to that language like feature "y", which also has its own tag.  It doesn't really make sense to have a question tagged "y" without an "x" tag, or worse with some other unrelated language tag.

If it does not already exist I would suggest adding this feature as it could help prevent mislabeling (keep in mind I have no idea how difficult or even if this possible to do).

Some tags I would suggest to add it to:

[c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) is required to post [constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/constexpr) or [user-defined-literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-literals)

I am sure there are others for other languages but I cannot think of any.

Answer (score 2):

No. While there are tags which logically should be used in conjunction with some other tag, no tag actually requires the use of some other tag.

And generally speaking... there's no real reason to do so. Do we get a lot of people mistagging questions in this way? The worst thing I've ever seen in this regard is people using version specific tags without using the main tag (Qt5 without Qt itself, for example). I don't think correcting such "mistakes" are worth adding a feature for.

Here's another reason why not to. Technically, `constexpr` and `user-defined-literals` should be attached to `c++11`, which itself should be attached to `c++`. So using any one of those tags now takes up 3 of the 5 tag slots for a question. That's a lot.

Just let the user make the decision about which tags are appropriate for use.